# NativeScript Install, Build, Deploy and Run performance analysis

Tags: android, performance, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

These are the steps required to run NativeScript App on simulator/Device

1. $tns install
2. $tns platform add android
3. $tns build android
4. $tns run android --emulator

Steps 1-3 are one time only, but on my machine it takes about 15-30 minutes.
and step 4 also take 10-20 minute **each time**( each time I run the app it should be less).

I have

- 16GB Ram
- Intel i5 processor

Does anybody else facing same issues/probles, i have already reinstalled windows 7.
or this is $tns command issue. $Ionic running ok.

Comment: I have found out the issue, it is gradle copy files from /node_modules to /tns_modules taking time. it is extremely slow.

Answer (score 2):

Your timings are scary! Even on my dummy Celeron 1000M with 4G RAM I am running a fresh app within seconds. I guess that you either have some environment problems or network related problems (which are maybe causing your dependencies from npm to halt!?)

Btw **tns run android** will prepare, build, deploy and run your app (even with no platforms added before that)

You can try the following

```
tns create myApp
tns run android --log trace
```

And look what is causing the delay.

Also, are you using AVD or Genymotion for emulating? make sure they are started before running g your tns commands and leave them open to avoid the initial start. AVD is often slow when executed and somites are timing out.Check out some information about the android emulator [here](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/is-your-android-emulator-just-too-slow)

Comment: Emulator are very fast after enabling intel virtualization technology and yes i run emulator before running my app, $tns run android --log trace doesn't give you anything since each steps taking whole lot of time like hooks are taking most of the time and after successful build it keep copying all the dependency from node_modules to tns_modules.